# Create a table where some columns are calculated using data from other columns

Tags: sql

I want to create a table in SQL where two of the columns are values calculated using data that already exists in the database. For example, I've created an ingredient table which holds the ingredient price and I want to create a Menu table which holds the main ingredient used in the food (foreign Key) as well as the production & sale prices (example below)

`Ingredient` table:

```
IngredientID
IngredientName
Price
```

`MenuItem` table:

```
FoodID
FoodName
IngredientID (foreign Key)
Production Cost (double the price of the ingredient)
Sale Cost (double the production cost)
```

(The prices all being double is just used as an example)

I really don't know how to go about this as I'm really new to SQL

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server are *completely* different products. Only tag the one you are *really* using.

Comment: What you are proposing looks to be a bad design, in my opinion. You might calculate `MenuItem` costs on insert, but if the `Ingrediant` costs change, the `MenuItem` costs would become stale.  It might be better to define `MenuItem` to only have the first three columns.  You could then define a *view* that joins the two tables and performs the necessary calculations. You probably also want to consider use cases where a `MenuItem` is made of of more than one `Ingredient`, which would likely require many-to-many relationship using a *junction table* instead of a direct foreign key reference.

Comment: Hi, one option is to go with a View or if your table is part of a ETL load process then you can use a Materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

We do have a computed column in sql server when you create a table, but it cannot use data from other table. Please try with a function, or create a view for it

Function, it's easy to read, but I think loading data could be slow, since it's calculating on the fly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPrice(@IngredientId)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Price int
    select @Price = Price from Ingredient where Ingredient= @Ingredient
    RETURN @Price
END

create table MenuItem 
(
FoodId INT,
FoodName varchar(100),
IngredientId INT,
ProductionCost as dbo.GetPrice(IngredientId),
SaleCost AS ProductionCost *2 
)
```

View is like this

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Food AS
(
SELECT m.FoodId, m.FoodName, IngredientId, i.Price *2 as ProductionCost, i.Price*2*2 as SaleCost
FROM dbo.MenuItem m
JOIN dbo.Ingredient i
    on m.IngredientId = i.IngredientId
)
```

Good thing about view is, it is updated every time when you call it. and you don't have to worry about the performance when you load data